# Cauchy- Schwarz inequality

Tags: normal-distribution, random-variable, inequality

In Gaussian random vector,the correlation of two random variables is always between -1 and +1.

How to check this fact by application of Cauchy- Schwartz inequality which states that

$E(XY)≤(EX^2)^{0.5} (EY^2)^{0.5}$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/564751/how-can-i-simply-prove-that-the-pearson-correlation-coefficient-is-between-1-an

Comment: The portion of your question stating "In Gaussian random vector," is superfluous for random variables with finite values.

Comment: All you need to do is divide both sides of this inequality by the right hand side.